# How do you parse a multipart form in Vercel node.js app?

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless, vercel

I'm trying to parse a multipart form in Vercel node.js application, I tried many of the libraries such as formidable, busboy, multiparty ... but none are picking up on the "file" or parse events. What is the proper way of doing this?

I can see the file content properly available in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind ... I fixed by adding:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```